# How electric signal is converted to more powerful electricity

Tags: signal, converter, pins

First a little disclaimer: I've a newbie question which is simple, but somehow I can't explain it to myself.
I'm interested in how electrical signals can trigger let's say a movement, which requires much more electricity. Let's say that a controller sets a signal on one of its PINs and this causes some rotation in a motor. The rotation requires much more power, than this signal can provide, so somehow the signal is augmented or boosted. Is this the work of a voltage converter? Can you please explain to me how this mechanism works?
Thanks

Comment: The class of devices has various names, drives, controllers or interface depending.  A simple H-bridge motor controller would take 2 to 4 digital inputs to control the speed, direction and regenerative breaking of a motor.  A simple relay could be switched with a transistor from a single digital pin and turn a motor (of any chosen size) on and off.  There is no limit to the complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A power amplifier is usually what is used. Think of a microphone signal (just a few milli volts at very low current). The output from a microphone in electrical terms is barely a milli watt or so yet, this can be amplified up to incredible levels for blasting out over a [tannoy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannoy), megaphone or the stage of a rock band (probably around 1000 watts).

Similarly power amplifiers can be used to control electrical motors from very small signals.

A "voltage converter" isn't really defined in terms of anything much - the real mechanism boosts power.